# how to use return with string in java

Tags: java, string, return

I have this java code and I want to use return to return a String from a method to a class, but I can't figure out how to use the returned String in this class:

```
private class NumsysAction implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String numsys_pushed = event.getActionCommand();

    if (active_numsys==2 && numsys_pushed.equals("DEC")) {
    chng_numsys_bin_dec(display.getText());

    ?????
   }


 }
}
```

This is the method I want to use to return a String:

```
public String chng_numsys_bin_dec(String chng_numsys_input) {
  String chng_numsys_output = "String I want to return";   

  return chng_numsys_output;
}
```

What do I have to write where the questionmarks are to put the returned String called "chng_numsys_output" into a new String variable?

Comment: You probably want to show the return as text in other component, so all you need to do is to set the text of other component as the result of `chng_numsys_bin_dec` invocation. You don't want to return it ;)

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is, but normally you need to assigned a return value to some variable, before you can do anything with it. So you will need something like `String returnValue = chng_numsys_bin_dec(display.getText());` _before_ the question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (active_numsys==2 && numsys_pushed.equals("DEC")) {
    String newStringVariable = chng_numsys_bin_dec(display.getText());
    // now use it
}
```

Comment: What if you want to use it outside of the `if`?

Comment: @Makoto Outside of the `if`, huh? The line could also be outside of the `if` without any problems.

Comment: @noone, are you sure ? I am afraid your answer is wrong. Anything you declare to be inside the `actionPerformed` function is local to that function. The OP needs to return the value, or get the value to be used later one outside of the function.

Comment: @user3029102, you said you want to return the string. How come this worked just fine ?

Comment: @Sage: yeah, I wanted to return the string from "public String chng_numsys_bin_dec()" and use it in my "private class NumsysAction" and I was able to do that as noone described

Comment: @user3029102, it looks strange to me that: you know how to call a function, how to return from it but don't know how to assign a variable to returned value and use it. Anyways, your problem is solved. And That's all that matters

Answer (score 0):

Upon `Action Event`: we don't return things, we just do things by capturing some value from the Controlling component which is the source of the event. actionPerformed funciton belongs to `ActionListener` interface. It has `void` return type. If you need to capture and use the value, then use a String variable by declaring in the class context of `NumsysAction`. Then you will be able to use the variable by referencing it from the instance of `NumsysAction` class.

```
private class NumsysAction implements ActionListener {

    public String chngNumSysDec = "";   

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String numsys_pushed = event.getActionCommand();

    if (active_numsys==2 && numsys_pushed.equals("DEC")) {
       chngNumSysDec = chng_numsys_bin_dec(display.getText());


   }

  public String getChngNumSysBinDec() //<------ here declaring a function
  {
       return chngNumSysDec; 
  }

 }
}
```